# How to pass custom parameters to the DialogFlow CX from the Twilio flow

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-cx, twilio-flow

I have a Twilio channel as fallows. it is already connected with google DialogFlow CX virtual agent.

[image]

I'm using following python code to start outbound call and start conversation with dialog flow agent.

```
    execution = client.studio.v2.flows('flowId').executions.create(parameters={
                'name': 'John Doe',
                'date': '2023-07-15',
                'time': '7:00 PM',
                'numberOfGuests': 4,
                'contactDetails': '555-1234'
}, to= '+to number', from_= '+from number')
```

I want to know how to pass capture this vales from Twilio studio. and pass it to Virtual agent also how to capture that values from the DialogFlow CX?

Comment: Hi @Suravi, Have you checked this [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/connect/virtualagent/virtualagent-dialogflow-cx#custom-parameters) ? let me know if this helps you or not.

Comment: Hi @DhirajSingh, yes I have checked that documentation. it is TwiML documentation I want to know how to pass this Twilio studio. and how to capture that values from the DialogFlow CX

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Support Engineer here. When you pass parameters to the `executions.create` method, they become available in Studio in the form of Flow Data and can be accessed using the standard Liquid syntax. So for example, `'name': 'John Doe'` can be accessed in Studio by using `{{flow.data.name}}`. Then, in the Connect Virtual Agent widget, you can pass those values in the Parameters section:

[image: Twilio Studio screenshot showing the Connect Virtual Agent widget]